# image animation cropped by layout bounds

Tags: android, animation

I have an image that gets scaled from large to small as it spins. It's mean to be a fancy animation to simulate a tile being place on a board. The animation works as expected except for one thing: This image is cropped.

Each row of tiles is inside of a Horizontal LinearLayout. Each LinearLayout is inside of another LinearLayout (Vertical). This give the board. Sadly, the image animation is getting cropped to not excede the bounds of the parent layout. I don't want that. I want the image to be displayed and animated as if it's on top of everything else. I want it to exceed the layout.

Any idea how to fix this?

Here's a couple of screenshots:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your image is constrained to fit within it's parent view as per design. You might want to use a canvas to hold all your tiles instead (keep in mind the bounds of the canvas for the corners otherwise you will have the same issue), or look into other layouts that might be able to accommodate your needs.

From: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html

Note: Regardless of how your animation may move or resize, the bounds of the View that holds your animation will not automatically adjust to accommodate it. Even so, the animation will still be drawn beyond the bounds of its View and will not be clipped. However, clipping will occur if the animation exceeds the bounds of the parent View.

Comment: Right. I get that. I guess the real question is this: What's the Android layout equivalent to the CSS `overflow: visible` attribute?